# Query using GIN or GIST index does not run concurrently

Tags: postgresql

I noticed this query does not run concurrently:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mytable WHERE ARRAY[1,2]::integer[] && array_col::integer[];
```

Running one concurrent queries takes 120s
Running two concurrent queries takes 240s
Running three concurrent queries queries takes 360s

The table is quite big with 32mil records. The server has 32 cores and 230GB of memory using pgtune settings. There is no iowait according to top.

Ive used each of these indexes individually, with similar results:

```
CREATE INDEX mytable_gist ON mytable USING GIST(array_col gist__intbig_ops);

CREATE INDEX mytable_gin ON mytable USING GIN(array_col gin__int_ops);
```

Im running EXPLAIN ANALYZE right now which is taking forever, so I thought id post without to see if someone already knows whats up.

Comment: `explain analyze` can't take longer than 120s (as the statement only takes that long)

Comment: you should to verify, so indexes are used. Try use just EXPLAIN. Theoretically you can get bottleneck from memory controller. What I know, there is not any exclusive lock.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - explain analyze should be slower. Try EXPLAIN ANALYZE (timing false) ... if your postgres supports it.

Comment: @PavelStehule: yes a *bit* slower but not to the extend that a query that takes 120s without explain takes "forever" *with* explain.

Answer (score 0):

My first guess is that your three "concurrent" queries are going over the same connection and to the same back-end.  Back-ends can run concurrently with eachother but they cannot themselves run several queries concurrently (they are single-threaded).

I say this because PostgreSQL is pretty good concurrency-wise, and many concurrent queries on the same tables can usually piggy-back on eachother's disk I/O, so it would make no sense to me if these were really running serially on *different* backends.

If this is incorrect, please edit the question to include exactly how you are running the queries.